# Java: Given a HashMap whose values are arrays what is the best way to manipulate values of those arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have an HashMap and I want to edit specific entries in those values by index. I am confused syntactically  on how to do this as my main tools seem to be set/get and get just seems to be a reference instead of the actual value.

In pseudocode it would look something like:

```
dictionary.get(n)[x] += 1
```

but in Java I feel like I'd have to be doing something like:

```
dictionary.set(n,dictionary.get(n).set(x, dictionary.get(n).get(x) + 1))
```

which is disgusting!

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a `HashMap` of arrays of primitive numbers, then I think your “pseudo-code” is actually the answer to your question. :)

Comment: I suggest you test your first code. You will find that it works. If you want to modify the array, you do indeed need a reference to it.

Comment: Why do you think you would need to set the value again in the map when you update the array? That is not how arrays (or maps) and references in general work in Java.